# PHP echo called by Ajax showing in 'network' section of chrome inspect but not on index file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a php file.  This php file has a basic jquery ajax call in an external js file, which works perfectly (I can see this from the network section of chrome inspect).  It calls a very basic php:

```
<?php
    if($_REQUEST['option'])
    {
    $_SESSION['selected']=$_REQUEST['option'];
echo $_SESSION['selected'];
}
die();
?>
```

Now when I click on function.php in the network section of chrome inspect, the preview shows the name perfectly, however none of this output comes up on the screen.

I have tried using sessions and including function.php, but neither work.

Please help me.

UPDATE: It is now working with a simple echo, but only when the page refreshes.  How would I make an echo when a value was clicked?

Comment: where is `session_start();`  ?
also are you passing `option` parameter in request?

Comment: @Ravi I have added session_start(); and option is being passed in the request

Comment: Well, output to the screen ( to the document body )  must be realized by your js script ( if you call this script with ajax request ). Do you implement this ?

Comment: Now it works, but only on page refresh

Comment: I will add the script, @VasilVanchuk

Comment: something about $.get('function.php?option=123', function(response){ $('<div></div>').text(response).appendTo($(document.body));}); if you use jQ

Comment: @VasilVanchuk It turns out the script is fine, I just need a way to make a php variable echo onclick, I have an idea...

Comment: you can't update page only by php ( without refresh ). You must use javascript to  update page - make ajax request and on success modify page

Comment: @VasilVanchuk so what function would I use in JavaScript to print to the body without removing the whole page?

Comment: you can use document.getElementById('idElementForMessage').innderHTML = responseText . Or create new element. Give example of your page and your script to get more information

Comment: I'll try document.write

Comment: var selected = "<?php echo $_SESSION['selected']; ?>";
            document.write(selected);

Comment: gives a blank page (I added it to the success function)